# Interactive tree diagrams

Tags: offline, diagram

I need to build a tree diagram which should be interactive. Mainly, I'm looking for a tool that allows me to add a *hidden* description for each node, so that when I click on a node a window pops up with that description.

I prefer an offline tool, but online tools are fine too. Moreover, it should not be too expensive (e.g., 50$ are fine but not more).

Answer (score 1):

You can try either of the followings:

MS Visio

SmartDraw

or this "https://www.yworks.com/products/yed" -- It works for me and its free

Comment: Thanks for the answer but none of them seems to do what I am looking for. The pop-up windows thing.